# MYSQL фильтр видов имен

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли из такой таблицы:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Антон |
| 2 | Вика |
| 3 | Антон |
| 4 | Саша |
| 5 | Рита |
| 6 | Антон |
| 7 | Антон |
| 8 | Вика |

Нужно с помощью запроса, получить такой список:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Антон |
| 2 | Вика |
| 4 | Саша |
| 5 | Рита |

(в БД некоторые имена упоминались несколько раз, но после запроса, я получил все имена которые имеются в БД но без повторений)

**Возможно ли такое реализовать?**

Comment: https://oracleplsql.ru/distinct-mysql.html   ......... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, большое спасибо!